# Authentication failed using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-8

When I post a user name and password it is returning a request error ERR_BAD_REQUEST.

I get the user's name and password from react, if it's ok I let it advance to the next page:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validacao = validator($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validacao->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['erros' => $validacao->errors()], 400);
        }

        if (auth()->attempt(['name' => $request->name, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return response()->json(['name' => auth()->user()]);
        }

        return response()->json(['erros' => ['login' => 'Usuário ou senha inválidos']], 406);
    }
}
```

follow my model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Campo de senha à ser utilizado no login.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

}
```

Comment: what's in your : $request->all()

Comment: (
    [name] => admin
    [password] => 12345
)